# react-native-camera runs slowly while navigating back from a camera screen

Tags: react-native, react-native-camera

It also runs slowly while navigating forward to a camera screen before i do this:

```
componentDidMount() {
    super.componentDidMount();

    // 延迟处理
    InteractionManager.runAfterInteractions(() => {
        this.setState({
            created: true
        });
    });
}

render() {
    return <View style={PublicStyles.screenView}>
        {this.state.created ? <RNCamera/> : null}
    </View>
}
```

Then, what should i do to solve the problem that happen while navigating back?

Comment: Can you give us more details about your problem, I don't quite understand the issue. What do you mean by "navigating back and forward to a camera"?

Comment: Sorry, my English is not very good. What I want to say is "Switch between two screens"